# How to get a Type.Name that includes generic parameters?

Tags: .net, reflection

`new List<int>().GetType().Name` is List`1. How do I get a name more like `List<int>` (**not** `List<T>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be using `new List<int>().GetType().ToString()`, which returns `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ``.

Or you could write yourself a small helper method along the lines of:

```
string GetShortName(Type type)
{
    string result = type.Name;
    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        // remove genric indication (e.g. `1)
        result = result.Substring(0, result.LastIndexOf('`'));

        result = string.Format(
            "{0}<{1}>",
            result,
            string.Join(", ",
                        type.GetGenericArguments().Select(t => GetShortName(t))));
    }

    return result;
}
```

which outputs strings like:

```
List<Int32>
List<T>
Dictionary<List<Double>, Int32>
Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>
```

Note that for nested types, this would return only the innermost name.

Comment: Is it unavoidable to do a bunch of manual processing to remove all the namespace prefixes and the `1?

Comment: Yes it is. There might be some internal helpers in Microsoft assemblies to get a compilable name, but they're internal.

Comment: @Qwertie, I don't know about a way to remove the \`1 without string processing, but see my update for a way to remove the namespace prefixes and to get `<>`s instead of `[]`s.

Comment: You code is .NET 4 specific (specifically that overload of string.Join, luckily I already wrote an equivalent method for .NET 2.)

Comment: @Qwertie, in .Net 3.5, you can just add `.ToArray()` there and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format("{0}<{1}>",GetType().Name, typeof(T).Name)
```

Edit: es pointed out in the comment, this is usefull inside a generic class, f.e. to distinct individual generic type arguments for overloads of lets say ToString(). Most the time, there is no point in querying the {0} first argument above, since it does not change in the same class. So one could just as well use:

```
String.Format("List<{0}>", typeof(T).Name)
```

Comment: You could use this only inside a generic type with type argument `T` (which doesn't make much sense to me) and certainly not when all you had is an instance of `System.Type`.